# How to initialize Dictionary<T, List<U>> with data

Tags: c#

I am trying to define a variable as below:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>().Add("some key",new List<string> {"some string"});
```

and getting following error:

> cannot implecitly convert type void to type
>   System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary>

can someone help to make me understand the syntax on how to define dictionary variable with inline data.

And why does this syntax compile?

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "some String" };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doing two things at once.  The right hand side of your expression looks like:

```
new Dictionary<string, List<string>>().Add("some key",new List<string> {"some string"});
```

You are creating a dictionary, and immediately adding an item to it.  `Add` returns void, so you aren't going to be able to capture the reference to your dictionary this way.  You want to first assign your dictionary to a variable, then add to it.

Or even better, you can use a collection initializer, like you are already doing with your `List`

```
var dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
              {
                  ["some key"] = new List<string> { "some string"}
              };
```

The above code uses C#6 syntax

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create the instance and execute a void method in the same statement and assign the result to a variable. You have to first initialize the variable and then perform the method:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dicData.Add("some key",new List<string> {"some string"}):
```

If you want to add the items upon initialization, you can do this (in C# 6, Visual Studio 2015):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
  {
       "some key",new List<string> {"some string"}
  },
  {
       "some other key",new List<string> {"some other string"}
  }
};
```

Comment: `You cannot create the object and execute Add in the same statement.`  You *absolutely* can.  This just isn't how you do that.  You could use a collection initializer to do *exactly* this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, in c# 6 you can do the following:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    { "some key", new List<string>() { "some string" } }
};
```

OR:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    ["some key"] = new List<string>() { "some string" },
    ["some key 2"] = new List<string>() { "some string 2" }
};
```